# Reversing a string, getting the same syntax error, any advice?

Tags: java, recursion

I am reversing a string for an assignment and I am getting one error since yesterday that is driving me crazy, it's at the third curly bracket }. Would anyone be able to advise me?. Here is what I have done anyway below, many thanks in advance!!.

```
public class RecursionQ2 {

    public RecursionQ2() {
    } 
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
public static String reverse(String str) {

    String Cheryl;
    if ((Cheryl == str) || (str.length() <=1)){
        return str;
    }
    return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
"}"
        + "
```

Comment: Not related but don't compare Strings using ==.

Comment: Do not use operator== to check *equality* of strings. Use `equals()` instead. (this does not answer this question, but will answer your next one). (Though in this case it seems to be only checking for nullity...)

Comment: You can't create a method inside another method.

Comment: and you cant write method inside your main method . . _or any other method_

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
public class RecursionQ2 {

    public RecursionQ2() {

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public static String reverse(String str) {

        String Cheryl = "";

        if (str != null) {
            if ((Cheryl.equals(str)) || (str.length() <= 1)) {
                return str;
            }
        }
        return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a look at the above, and made the changes and I put my string in after String Cheryl = "";, and there are no errors now, but it is returning nothing!!. What have I done??

Comment: Yes I have put in text there and nothing happened, will do it again!, kids on easter holidays have no mercy on being quiet for even 5 minutes for me!!!

Comment: have put in String Cheryl = "running is a good hobby"; and it has no errors, yet when I run it, nothing appears in the console and no errors either!. I apologise if I am annoying anyone.